# WCF services couldn't read configuration file

Tags: wcf, iis

I have created some WCF services in class library. 
These services need some configuration values to work properly. So i added these configurations to the web.config file after deploying the services on IIS.
The problem is that when i try to consume these services i get the following exception while reading the configurations:

> System.ArgumentException: exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.

Knowing that when i test the services it works fine before hosting them on IIS.

The question now what should i change to make the dll services able to be configured.

here is a portion of the web.config file.

```
    <children>
  <child name="service_config">
    <properties>
      <property name="connection_name" value="Photo" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="data_access_interface" value="data_access" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="is_client_db" value="false" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="exchange_service" value="exchange_service_key" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="max_file_size" value="1000" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="email_sender" value="test@gmail.com" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="email_body_template_name" value="test_files/Template.txt" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="tablet_photo_size_height" value="100" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="tablet_photo_size_width" value="90" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="phone_photo_size_height" value="200" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="phone_photo_size_width" value="180" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="phone_photo_optimized_size_height" value="80" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="phone_photo_optimized_size_width" value="60" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="web_photo_size_height" value="127" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="web_photo_size_width" value="170" valueType="System.String" />
      <property name="email_client_key" value="email_client_key" valueType="System.String" />
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're using `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to read a specified section(s) of the config file.  The error message you received gives you a good starting point for figuring out what the issue is - probably something to do with IIS not having a path to the exe.

You don't show the code you're using to get to the config file, and your posted configuration doesn't have a lot of context, so it's hard to tell you what to do.

However, I would use the `<appSettings>` section of the config file (available in both app.config and web.config files) to store these properties, and then you could retrieve them `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting[keyName]`.

Something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="connection_name" value="Photo" />
  <add key="data_access_interface" value=data_access" />
  <!-- plus the rest of your values -->
</appSettings>
```

Then you'd simply use something like:

```
string connectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection_name"];
string dataAccesInterface = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["data_access_interface"];
```

This would work whether you're running it as a stand alone exe or hosting it in IIS.

If there's a reason you don't want to (or can't) use the standard `<appSettings>` section, please update your question with the context around the `<children>` section plus how you're trying to access it so we can provide better guidance.

Comment: Actually i use an object factory library which need configuration in the children section. This error raises when i call this method:
 IConfiguration config = new WebConfigurationPersistenceManagerFactory().
                    CreatePersistenceManager().GetConfigurationProvider().GetConfiguration(configName);

Comment: @ManS - Is this something you wrote or some other developer/vendor?  Do you have documentation for it?  Without knowing anything about this object factory library it's going to be very hard for anyone here to help you.  You should really update your question with this information.